# Package upload failed. APK has not been signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload our app to the **Google Play** app store. The app is built with *Azure DevOps* and deployed to *AppCenter*. When trying to publish to **Google Play** from *AppCenter* I am getting this error message in *AppCenter*.

**Package upload failed. APK has not been signed with the upload certificate.**

[image]

The app is *signed* and *aligned* as part of the build and this is the first version of the app (I am not updating a previous version of the app). The build uses the same keystore every build.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use Build/Generate signed bundle? that is not the same as just running a release version of of your app and uploading that apk.

Comment: Yes I have generated a signed bundle using a keystore.

Comment: had to ask, that got me a few times

Comment: There are also 2 checkboxes in the build menu for the signature type.  [I have them both checked ]

Comment: It seems that my manager had uploaded the initial version of the app to Google Play using a different keystore to the one used by the build. I've now sorted the problem :)

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing. Use exact jks file